# find integer from Nth field in awk

Tags: regex, parsing, awk

I've got a script producing output from Twitter's streaming API into a format like this

```
semmelracet_dev | 450587667 | 1 semla till idag! #semmelreport | 569866960802062336 | 1424701845728
```

Where field 3 is the actual tweet.

What I want to do was to grab the integer from that field and insert it into a database as a separate field/column.

To just insert those fields is not a problem, but getting the INT and handling it separately is. Could I enforce usage and split the field after the INT?

Sorry about not including expexted output. Basically i'm constructing a mysql insert like

```
"... insert into report values ("semmelracet_dev", 450587667, "1 semla till idag! #semmelreport", 1, 569866960802062336, 1424701845728)"
```

Any ideas?

EDIT again, or if it's something that's not doable, maybe keep all the columns and in field 3 just keep the int when inserting them into the database?

EDIT 2

Tried the solution from jeanrjc below with mixed success

```
cat tweetReport.txt | awk -F"\|" '{n=split($3,s," "); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if
(s[i] + 0 == s[i]) int_val = s[i]}{print "\""$1"\","$2", \""$3"\",
"int_val", "$4", "$5}')
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

I then removed the trailing ) and got

```
cat tweetReport.txt | awk -F"\|" '{n=split($3,s," "); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if     
(s[i] + 0 == s[i]) int_val = s[i]}{print "\""$1"\","$2", \""$3"\",
"int_val", "$4", "$5}'

awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'
"semmelracet_dev ", 450587667 , " 1 semla till idag! #semmelreport ", 1,
569866960802062336 ,  1424701845728 "",, "", 1, ,
```

Which is better, but with some jibberish i don't quite understand..

Comment: Show your expected output from above text?

Comment: Is the integer always the 1st string in $3? Can there be anything else in that location? If there's a few variations of that field it'd be best to show them.

Comment: I could require users to always put the int first in the tweet, but users being  users I wouldn't trust that to work and i would end up fixing in the DB. If there is a neat way to extract the INT in the third field and put it into a separate field when constructing the insert that would be super duper

Comment: I edited and remove the trailing `)` and it works fine (ie. as I showed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, but I guessed that you wanted to extract (or get rid of) the int value of the 3rd field, is that right ?

To do so:

```
awk -F"|" '{print $3}' file | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i + 0 == $i) print $i}'
```

where `($i + 0 == $i)` tests whether this word is an int or not, then print it.

I hope that from that, you'll manage to get what you want. Precise your expected output otherwise.

EDIT : To obtain desired output:

```
$ cat tweet.txt
semmelracet_dev | 999999999 | 2 foo  bar! #fooreport | 999996696080209999 | 1429999845728
semmelracet_dev | 450587667 | 1 semla till idag! #semmelreport | 569866960802062336 | 1424701845728


$ awk -F"\|" '{n=split($3,s," "); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if (s[i] + 0 == s[i]) int_val = s[i]}{print "\""$1"\","$2", \""$3"\", "int_val", "$4", "$5}' tweet.txt 

"semmelracet_dev ", 999999999 , " 2 foo  bar! #fooreport ", 2,  999996696080209999 ,  1429999845728
"semmelracet_dev ", 450587667 , " 1 semla till idag! #semmelreport ", 1,  569866960802062336 ,  1424701845728
```

Which you can capture in a variable and then pass it to construct your mysql insert.

HTH

Comment: i want to extract the int value and keep it in a variable to insert into my table in a separate column, i outlined my expected or wanted  output above in another comment.. thanks

Comment: @Martin do NOT provide important information in comments as it can't be formatted and everyone you're asking to help you would have to go looking for it. Just edit your question to contain all relevant information.

Comment: thanks! much better but not quite for me, please have a look at the updated question for exact outcome

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a bashism to feed data to awk, you can use something else:

```
$ t="semmelracet_dev | 450587667 | 1 semla till idag! #semmelreport | 569866960802062336 | 1424701845728"
$ awk -F'|' '{n=$3;sub(/^ */,"",n);sub(/ .*/,"",n);print n;}' <<<"$t"
1
```

This simply does a couple of substitutions to "trim" data around the pipe, then remove anything after the first space.

If you want help inserting this number into a database, you'll have to be a bit more explicit about what tools you're using.  For example, this might work:

```
$ n=$(awk -F'|' '{n=$3;sub(/^ */,"",n);sub(/ .*/,"",n);print n;}' <<<"$t")
$ psql -c $(printf 'INSERT INTO table (n) VALUES (%d);' "$n")
```

Or if you'd prefer to get these data from a log file and pipe thing through psql, you could do it this way:

```
awk -F'|' -vfmt="INSERT INTO table (n) VALUES (%d);" '
  {
    n=$3; sub(/^ */,"",n); sub(/ .*/,"",n);
    printf(fmt,n);
  }' input.txt \
| psql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";} {print($3);}' | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)(.*)/\1/'
```

Comment: You never need sed if you're using awk: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {print gensub(/([0-9]+).*/,"\\1","",$3)}'`.

Comment: Sorry about not including expexted output. Basically i'm constructing a mysql insert like "... insert into report values ("semmelracet_dev", 450587667, "1 semla till idag! #semmelreport", 1, 569866960802062336, 1424701845728)"